# How to read data only when a value is above or under a certain threshold

Tags: c++, iot, xbee, mbed

This may sound a little vague but I will try my best to clarify. Basically I am using an mbed (FRDM k64f) device which sends data to another device via XBee. My question is,

How do I get it to send data only when float mX,mY or mZ(see code below) are above or under a certain threshold, so the rest of the time it is asleep. 
Is this possible?

So currently it is sending data every 5 seconds but I would like to change that.

Here is my current code

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "C12832.h" //for LCD
#include "FXOS8700Q.h"// for magnetometer

Ticker timer;
DigitalOut gpo(D0);
DigitalOut led(LED_RED);
Serial xbee(D1, D0);
C12832 shld_lcd (D11, D13, D12, D7, D10);
FXOS8700Q_mag mSensor(PTE25, PTE24, FXOS8700CQ_SLAVE_ADDR1);
MotionSensorDataUnits mData;

//int tick = 0;

void setup() {
    xbee.baud(9600);
}

/*
 void attime() {
    tick++;
 }
  */        
int main()
{
    //timer.attach(&attime, 1);
    mSensor.enable();
    setup();
    while (1) {
        wait(5);
        mSensor.getAxis(mData);
        float mX = mData.x;
        float mY = mData.y;
        float mZ = mData.z;
        xbee.printf("%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \r\n",mX,mY,mZ);




    }
}
```

Comment: Use an if statement to check if the variables are in the range you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a conditional expression:

```
while(1) {
    wait(5);
    msensor.getAxis(mData);
    float mX = mData.x;
    float mY = mData.y;
    float mZ = mData.z;
    if (mX >= mX_threshold && mY >= mY_threshold && mZ >= mZ_threshold)
        xbee.printf("%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \r\n",mX,mY,mZ);
}
```

where `mX_threshold` (and similarly for Y and Z) are the threshold constraints you want.

Comment: sorry Just realized how simple it actually was, thanks.